# How should I cover an empty space between a fence post and a garage wall?

Tags: gates

Below is the 1000 words picture. How do I cover that empty space?
The hinges are at the opposite end of the gate

[image]

How about this:
[image]
This will be done by ripping of a post in half (45%) and then that will be attached to the existing post. On that I will screw small horizontal boards made of the remainings of the 6x8 cedar boards that I used to build the gate

Comment: I know it is done already, but you could have just extended those new boards to fly right to the brick.

Comment: I wish I had that idea.. at a second thought I think this would look too ugly, it will make the gate look more like a fence segment and the lines of screws that you can see in the picture will look off center (they are already that way but to a lesser degree)

Comment: making those boards too long would have implications on how far from the gate you have to stay when you open that gate

Comment: Perfect balance of function and form.  Feng Shui all the way. Looks exactly right in the second drawing. No need to look any further. That's the way I would do it, too.

Comment: I am trying to understand if you are being caustic here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Rip a 45 degree notch down the center of a post (4 x 4 x hgt of gate) and install into a post anchor bracket and than afix to the brick mortar joints with TapCon screws. Or TapCon a 2 x 4 to one edge of the corner and cap the edge with another 2 x 4 on the other corner edge. If you can dig a hole sink a metal or wooden post and attach a fence board to it. Pour a cement footing and build a brick pillar with those left over half bricks. Attach a dog-eared fence board to the edge of the gate. Or install 2 angle brackets, bent to 22.5 degrees, to the mortar joints of the brick wall (with TapCons) and attach fence board to the bracket. Or pour a footing and install concrete block on edge, wrap extruded metal lathing around it, and trowel on a stucco finish.

Comment: I forgot to add a comment here, what about the solution that I just added to my initial question? As you can see the mortar between the bricks is old and it already has more holes than I would like, I did not want to aggravate the situation even more and to attach anything to that corner.